# How do I install telnet on windows 10 (Not enable, actually install)

Tags: windows-10, telnet

I'm running a modified windows 10, meaning I went though the ISO and removed a bunch of stuff, runs super smooth. Anyway I suspect that telnet is one of the things that I pulled out because now, couple years down the line, that I want to use it it's missing from the features list.

So is there a way I can reinstall it?

Comment: You would need to use a Windows 10 ISO to install this feature. Why don’t you just a third-party client instead?

Comment: Can you tell us exactly how you modified the ISO.  Did you modify the WinSxS?

Comment: I think I did yeah, though its been some years so I cant remember what exactly I removed. I've tried a bunch off stuff and none of it seems to work so I'll probably settle for using third-party. 
On that note, is there a nice telnet plugin for vscode? I'm mainly using it to send test commands to servers.
I've been using putty but having to reopen it each time the server restarts is getting on my nerves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows ordinary repairs are unlikely to find things you removed.

**(A) Try: DISM and restart.**

(1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

**(B) Then, if that does not work, try installing Telnet with Power Shell.**

[Install Telnet](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-ca/000122433/how-to-install-telnet-client)

> Perform the following steps to install Telnet Client on a server
> running Windows Server Core.
>
> ```
>  1. Type Start PowerShell in the Command Prompt window to start Windows PowerShell.
>
>  2. Type Install-WindowsFeature Telnet-Client and press Enter to install the Telnet Client .
> ```

**(C) If all fails, try a third party Telnet app. I like and use Net Term.**

Comment: Sadly this did not work, seems like I'll need to find a unmodified ISO and install telnet from there. Which I have no Idea where it is. So third party I guess.

Comment: Windows 10 out the box works very well and is fast. You may wish to consider reinstalling Windows to have all you want and just hide what you do not want.

Comment: @DragonEpep - Use DISM to install the feature and use a mounted Windows 10 ISO as the source

Comment: Yes I might do that if I find my ISO. I am planning on reinstalling my OS at some point, but then I'll probably be switching my main PC to Linux, maybe set up a PCIE passthrough for a windows VM. For now I got Solar putty and that works quite well. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

On the command-prompt, try:

```
dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:TelnetClient
```

Comment: If the author has modified WinSxS directory as I suspect, this command won’t work, without using a Windows 10 ISO.

Comment: should be the right answer. thanks. can't believ microsoft made things so hard having Linux as a role model